# Can't log in on murmur with SuperUser

Tags: linux, mumble

I have set up a [murmur server](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) today on my server computer running Ubuntu server.

First time my Superuser log in did work, then I did changed my router bridge to get it working better, after that I can't log in with my Superuser account.

I have this error, "Wrong password for registered users". What can I do next? I am 100% sure that my password is correct.